# Type error with simple where-clause with Haskell's beam

Tags: haskell, haskell-beam

I am trying to create a select query with a simple where-clause using Haskell's beam. From https://haskell-beam.github.io/beam/user-guide/queries/select/#where-clause, I believed that this would work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

module Lib where

import Data.Int ( Int32 )
import Data.Word ( Word32 )
import Database.Beam

data FooT f
    = Foo
    { _fooId :: Columnar f Int32
    , _fooBar :: Columnar f Word32
    }
    deriving (Generic, Beamable)

instance Table FooT where
    data PrimaryKey FooT f =
        FooId (Columnar f Int32) deriving (Generic, Beamable)
    primaryKey = FooId . _fooId

type Foo = FooT Identity
type FooId = PrimaryKey FooT Identity

deriving instance Show Foo
deriving instance Eq Foo

data BazDb f = BazDb
    { _bazFoos :: f (TableEntity FooT)
    }
    deriving (Generic, Database be)

bazDb :: DatabaseSettings be BazDb
bazDb = defaultDbSettings

selectFoosByBar :: HasQBuilder be => Word32 -> SqlSelect be Foo
selectFoosByBar bar = select $
    filter_ (\foo -> _fooBar foo ==. bar) $
        all_ $ _bazFoos bazDb
```

but I am missing some vital detail, so I get the following compile error:

```
<SNIP>/Lib.hs:42:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘QGenExpr QValueContext be QBaseScope Word32’
                     with ‘Word32’
       Expected type: Word32
         Actual type: Columnar (QExpr be QBaseScope) Word32
    • In the first argument of ‘(==.)’, namely ‘_fooBar foo’
      In the expression: _fooBar foo ==. bar
      In the first argument of ‘filter_’, namely
        ‘(\ foo -> _fooBar foo ==. bar)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        foo :: FooT (QExpr be QBaseScope) (bound at src/Lib.hs:42:15)
        selectFoosByBar :: Word32 -> SqlSelect be Foo
          (bound at src/Lib.hs:41:1)
   |
42 |     filter_ (\foo -> _fooBar foo ==. bar) $
   |
```

Now, the error message itself is quite clear, but what I can't quite figure out is which side of `==.` I need to modify nor how to do it. Or if it's a matter of some missing extension or type annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant portions of the code

```
selectFoosByBar bar = select $
    filter_ (\foo -> _fooBar foo ==. bar) $
        all_ $ _bazFoos bazDb
```

If we look at `==.` you will see `(==.) :: SqlEq expr a => a -> a -> expr Bool`, so both sides of `==.` need to have the same type.

Now look at what is on the left of (==.) we see `_fooBar foo :: Columnar f Word32`. We can't get out of Columnar but we can make bar into something beam can work with using `val_`:

```
selectFoosByBar bar = select $
    filter_ (\foo -> _fooBar foo ==. val_ bar) $
        all_ $ _bazFoos bazDb
```

Notice this only work if we remove the type annotation. With a type annotation it will look like:

```
selectFoosByBar
  :: (HasQBuilder be, HasSqlEqualityCheck be Word32,
      HasSqlValueSyntax
        (Sql92ExpressionValueSyntax
           (Sql92SelectTableExpressionSyntax
              (Sql92SelectSelectTableSyntax
                 (Sql92SelectSyntax (BeamSqlBackendSyntax be)))))
        Word32) =>
     Word32 -> SqlSelect be (FooT Identity)
selectFoosByBar bar = select $
    filter_ (\foo -> _fooBar foo ==. val_ bar) $
        all_ $ _bazFoos bazDb
```

I think it needs this huge annotation so ghc can keep track of the `be` abstracted out backend.

Edit:
If we enable `ConstraintKinds` we can simplify the annotation:

```
type MagicSql be = 
      HasSqlValueSyntax
        (Sql92ExpressionValueSyntax
           (Sql92SelectTableExpressionSyntax
              (Sql92SelectSelectTableSyntax
                 (Sql92SelectSyntax (BeamSqlBackendSyntax be))))) 

selectFoosByBar
  :: (HasQBuilder be, HasSqlEqualityCheck be Word32, MagicSql be Word32) =>
     Word32 -> SqlSelect be (FooT Identity)
```

Comment: Great! I had tried `val_`, but the type constraints fooled me.

"I think it needs this huge annotation so ghc can keep track of the be abstracted out backend."

That turned out to be exactly the case, so as long as I am OK with restricting myself to a single back end, e.g `selectFoosByBar :: Word32 -> SqlSelect Postgres Foo` is ok as well.

Comment: Yeah, I would have tried that but I couldn't install any backends.

Answer (score 0):

On the offending line, `bar :: Word32` (per the signature of `selectFoosByBar`).

I *think* `_fooBar foo` is a `Columnar (something) Word32`.

The error message says the problem is with the first arg to `==.`, but looking at the [type of `==.`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/beam-core-0.9.1.0/docs/Database-Beam-Query.html#v:-61--61-.), I think you could change either side to get agreement.

Why is `bar :: Word32`? It makes intuitive sense; you're trying to filter by a word so the arg should be a word. That suggests that you probably want to do something to `_fooBar foo` to get a `Word32` "out of" it. That might be a straightforward function, but more likely it's going to be the opposite: somehow lifting your `==. bar` operation up into the "query expression" space.